# what is different between set ref in arrow function and set ref direct variable

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I know what refs doing in React. Usually I see this approach for setting ref:

```
<Example ref={ el => {this.example = el}} />
```

but sometimes I see this approach:

```
<Example ref={this.example} />
```

What's the difference?

Comment: Is `this.example` a string?

Comment: @Li357 I don't remmember what was the type. I just saw this methods and always has a question what's the difference between these two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Example ref={ el => {this.example = el}} />
```

In this method, it acts as a callBack function.  And the particular DOM element will be returned as an argument to 'this.example'.  So with that you can do manipulations to that DOM element for your requirement

`<Example ref={this.example} />`. This behaves similar to the above one, while this will attach a ref to the DOM element.  This method is frequently used when you want to attach a ref to child element and access it in parent Element

Refer this link for more learning: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-class-component

Answer (score 0):

Thet both are functions. In the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) you see `this.props.inputRef` being used, all this means is that the parent component can get a reference to that component via the callback function.

Assuming you are not using string refs (those are deprecated), `this.example` would be a member function doing the same as `el => {this.example = el}`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are two methods to provide ref for an element:
`<Example ref={el=>{this.example=el}}/>`
or 
`<Example ref="example" />`

please provide us with a working example about the last method you mentioned